# How can I enable ClearType fonts in Firefox?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, rendering, cleartype

Is there a way to enable ClearType font rendering in Firefox tabs, regardless of the O/S settings?

Some pages look awful on FF, while look much better in Internet Explorer. My understanding is that MS decoupled the ClearType definition of IE from the O/S. I'd like the same on FF.

Comment: Are the pages that look awful using standard fonts, or downloaded web fonts (Google fonts, for example)?  Does setting `gfx.font_rendering.cleartype.use_for_downloadable_fonts` to false help any?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - AFAICT, there's no difference.